# Pyinstaller executable not working with jinja2

Tags: windows, python-2.7, jinja2, pyinstaller

I have a python script that uses jinja2 and it works fine from the command line, but when I build an executable using PyInstaller it crashes on the point i create the environment object, to render the template.

Thanks,